# Why the need to limit what tags you can create documentation for?

Tags: support, documentation

Many of the niche technologies seem to suffer from the "Tag is to new or does not have enough activity".  I would like to understand why SO is limiting documentation for tags which have been ratified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not on the Docs team, but I'll offer a possible explanation: We don't want to have a huge number of ghost-town tags with documentation.

By requiring some level of activity in a tag before creating documentation for it, we have *some* assurance that there will be:

1. Enough people who know something about it to *create* content, and
2. Enough people who know enough to *vet* that content.

We also don't need a bunch of 3-question tag documentation pages filled with documentation on where to get quality handbags or other fine products. Documentation is, by nature, much more hidden than normal QA, so we need to make sure there are enough people around to *notice* spam and abuse happening in a Docs page.

Comment: I mean surely all of this is true of questions and answers too?!  I mean you don't need to know the technology to recognize spam.

Comment: @bated Questions and answers are inherently more visible - they bump the front page, and there are convenient ways for community projects to monitor all QA. That doesn't exist for documentation *yet*.

Comment: But surely you could limit the ability to add/edit documentation based on reputation.  This would filter out most the spam.